# Mapserver TabFile Error

Tags: mapserver, error

We would like to render a polygon on our MapServer.  Everything works wonderfully on our localhost.

Now we would like to send the application via external server. Everything works fine on the external server as well. Except that the polygon appears on the map. The polygon is a TabFile. All paths have been updated, adapted and checked several times.

In the network analysis comes with the "map".exe this error: `"No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty."`

Someone an idea what else would have to be adjusted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "No query information to decode. QUERY_STRING is set, but empty."

Is just the MapServer service saying it has no parameters to process the request.  It's a standard response.

For example the below service has the same response:

> http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGI/ows?

As you want to render a polygon (on a map), I'm guessing you have configured MapServer as a WMS, so you should get some XML output if you append the following parameters to your URL

```
request=GetCapabilities&service=WMS&
```

A map image would be something like:

```
service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&transparent=false&STYLES&WIDTH=1068&HEIGHT=952&crs=EPSG:4326&layers=ARTISANC&bbox=-2.000000,29.000000,4.500000,37.000000&
```

Where `crs=EPSG:XXXX&` is the projection of your data, `layers=xxxx&` is a list (one or more) layer names (not titles) from your service, and `bbox=aaaa,bbbb,cccc,dddd&` is the bounding box in the CRS for your area of interest.

For example:

http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGI/ows?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&width=700&height=450&styles=&layers=ARTISANC&format=application/openlayers&crs=EPSG:4326&bbox=-2.000000,29.000000,4.500000,37.000000

or

http://ogc2.bgs.ac.uk/cgi-bin/UGA_ARGI/ows?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetMap&width=700&height=450&styles&layers=BEDROCK_AGE,RAILWAY,ARTISANC&format=image/png&crs=EPSG:4326&bbox=-2.000000,29.000000,4.500000,37.000000

Rather than roll your own requests though you can use a client like QGIS to generate them for you (just supply the URL that gives the message above)...

Comment: Now it comes this error: ""msCGILoadMap (): Web application error. CGI variable" map "is not set." For our project we need several mapserv.exe, because we present different maps to different users (Mapfiles). Every time I come up with a new copy of the mapserv.exe this error message follows. Does anyone know this problem? Does something have to be considered when copying the file?

Comment: @hugo, glad you have progressed, please remember to give kudos by voting if you find any answer helpful